# match nodes on property, and include relationships between those nodes in the result

Tags: cypher

I have the following graph model to represent a microservice architecture

(:Team {space})-[:OPEX]->(:Service)-[:USES]->[:Service]

- a Team belongs to a space (a department)
- a Team has operation ownership (=OPEX) over several Services
- Services have USES relationships between them

My query in natural language:

- find all the Teams in a certain space, and via the OPEX relationship find all their Services
- also include all USES relationships between these services in the result

I'm having problems expressing this query in an elegant Cypher query. I came up with the following, but there must be an easier and more natural way to express it.

```
MATCH (t1:Team {space:"shopping"})-[o1:OPEX]->(s1:Service),
  (t2:Team {space:"shopping"})-[o2:OPEX]->(s2:Service),
  (s3:Service)-[u:USES]->(s4:Service)
WHERE s3.name=s1.name AND s4.name=s2.name
RETURN  t1, o1, s1, u, s2, o2, t2
```

Can someone point me into a better direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reuse variables that refer to the same instance, and you can use IN and COLLECT to find patterns in a set of nodes.

Something like this

```
MATCH (:Team {space:"shopping"})-[:OPEX]->(s:Service)
WITH COLLECT(s) as services
MATCH (t:Team {space:"shopping"})-[o:OPEX]->(s1:Service)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s1:Service)-[u:USES]->(s2:Service)
WHERE s1 in services AND s2 in services
RETURN t, o, s1, u, s2
```

Comment: Thnx Tezra! This query is definitely is more Cypher-like than my original SQL-like query.